# Disabling Fav icon click is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have a table in that two fa-icon buttons like plus and remove button inside href tag.Now I am checking the duplicate name for one column using blur it is working fine when name already exits i am going to disable the the icon not clickable in success function.Name is not there enabling it.It was working for button but icons it is not working why.Please Any help me.Below is my tried code.Thanks In Advance.

### My HTML

```
 <div class="txtcbt" style="float:left;width:4%;">
    <a id="add" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="width:40%;font-size:25px;color:white;background-color:#dc143c;"></i></a>
  </div>
```

### This is Jquery code for Enabling and disabling not working

```
success:function(response){
        var data = $.parseJSON(response);
          if(data==true){
          //if name is there it showing alert message but disabling is not working
           alert("vendor contact name already exits");
           $('.txtcbt #add .fa fa-plus').prop('disabled', true);
         }else{
            $('.txtcbt #add .fa fa-plus').prop('disabled', false);
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no disable attribute for a tag.
so add this in your css file.

```
<style>
    a.disabled {
       pointer-events: none;
       cursor: default;
    }
        </style>
```

Do this in your Script

```
success:function(response)
{
    var data = $.parseJSON(response);
    if(data==true)
    {
        //if name is there it showing alert message but disabling is not working
        alert("vendor contact name already exits");
        $('#add').attr('class', 'disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#add').attr('class', '');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain me the code for what is pointer-events none means and cursor default please thanks in advance..

Comment: It will just remove mouse events for the particular class. Because here we using <a> tag right so we can't just put enable disable functions, so we have to use like this.

Answer (score 0):

**I Hope this will helpful**

```
success:function(response)
{
    var data = $.parseJSON(response);
    if(data==true)
    {
        //if name is there it showing alert message but disabling is not working
        alert("vendor contact name already exits");
        $('#add').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#add').attr('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need some details. Is this in list? and check that id of <a> tag is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

for enabling
 $('#add.fa-plus').prop('disabled', false);

and for disable
 $('#add.fa-plus').prop('disabled', true);

If you  want to change fa icon from fa-plus. you can use **addClass** and **removeClass**

Comment: is it appended data?

Comment: No it is not appended data.